# Where does gradle save dependencies' jars?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I want to look at the jars/aars that are compiled when I add dependencies.

For example if I add this dependency in Gradle, where does it put the jar?

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:11.0.4'
}
```

Answer (score 64, accepted):

***BY DEFAULT***

Linux:

```
~/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1
```

Windows:

```
%USERPROFILE%/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1
```

Mac:

```
~/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1
```

Android:

```
no idea... can anyone edit?
```

***SETTING TO SOMETHING ELSE***

But you can override these default settings by setting `GRADLE_USER_HOME`.  The latter environment variable, if set, is **NOT** the same as `GRADLE_HOME`, which is the path to the directory containing the `bin/` directory for the Gradle version your system is using at the command prompt (NB instead of invoking Gradle directly at the command line most people seem to use the [Gradle wrapper](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_wrapper.html) however: `$ ./gradlew build`).

***RUNNING GRADLE IN AN IDE***

IDEs may be using a different version and be storing dependency jars somewhere else.  I only know Eclipse.  Having installed Buildship ("Eclipse Plug-ins for Gradle") the place to go is Window --> Preferences --> Gradle.  There is a box here for you to specify "Gradle User Home".  Mine is currently empty.  I presume it is using the system `GRADLE_USER_HOME` (which I have indeed set)... but I haven't bothered checking: although it is possible to run Gradle tasks from within Eclipse to me it is more handy to run Gradle commands in a separate Terminal (*nix)/Command Prompt window ('Doze).

Answer (score 30):

Generally, you can find in:

```
%USERPROFILE%/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1
```

Comment: This should be the answer

Answer (score 14):

Open your Android Studio **`Project Explorer`**, expand **`External Libraries`** sections. Right click and **`Show in Files/Explorer`**

Comment: In modern versions of Android Studio I'm not seeing that option on External Libraries, but if I drill into the specific jar within there, and right click on the jar, i do see an option to open in Finder, then i can back upwards from there to get all of the files.

Answer (score 1):

The format for the jar is `~/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/<com.org.pkg>/<uuid>/`

If you are using Intellij IDEA, then browse the jar on the Project window
[image]

Right-click on the jar and open in terminal.

Run the `pwd` command in terminal to find the location.

Video guide - [How to find dependent jar on local when using gradle](https://youtu.be/6qLOdL849Y0)