# Selenium starts old chromedriver version

Tags: selenium, gradle, web, driver, selenium-chromedriver

In my build.gradle file I have the following dependency:

```
compile group: 'org.seleniumhq.selenium', name: 'selenium-chrome-driver', version: '3.11.0'
```

However, whenever I start my tests, selenium seems to be using an old version of ChromeDriver, as it outputs in the console:

```
Starting ChromeDriver 2.31.488774
```

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: I think you are confusing chrome-driver API bindings, and the chrome-driver binary. The bindings you specify in your build.gradle. The binary you must download and install on your path; the latest binary version, at the time of this writing, is only 2.38.

Comment: ah damn.... yes true I installed the chromedriver executable with home-brew last year. Updated it and now everything works fine. Thanks so much man.

Answer (score 1):

If you dont provide the path of the executable Selenium will look in `$PATH` which might be where the old version is.
Since you are pulling a newer version on your gradle file make sure to pass the executable path when you instantiate the Remote Driver.

Comment: Thanks! However, where can I find the executable path if I build with gradle?

Comment: I am not very familiar with gradle but take a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46832288/where-does-gradle-save-dependencies-jars